# How to loop data in rows From DataGridView to a userform

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please help i need to edit data and save it back to the database,in the DataGridView the are checkbox which needs to be checked to show which data need to be modified after that it has to go to a userform row by row because the are some calculation which are to be performed before saving it, so far when the loop run once and does not pop up the form as many as the checkbox but it shows once and show 1 rows and stop

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim list_O_Array As New List(Of Integer)

FrmINI.Show()

For i = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows.Count() - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim dlt As Boolean
    dlt = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
    If dlt = True Then
        list_O_Array.Add(i)
    End If
Next

Dim tot As Integer

tot = list_O_Array.Count

For Each k As Integer In list_O_Array
    Dim cnt As Integer

    cnt = 0
    If cnt < tot Then
        frmAddItem.Show()

        frmAddItem.TxtHeading.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(1).Value
        frmAddItem.TxtPartNumber.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(2).Value
        frmAddItem.TxtQuantity.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(4).Value
        frmAddItem.TxtDescription.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value
        frmAddItem.TxtUnitCost.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(5).Value
        frmAddItem.TxtMarginValue.Text = FrmINI.DtGrdINI.Rows(k).Cells(8).Value
    end if
next
```

Comment: Show is not modal. When you call it the code continues immediately. How could your user changes something before you start your loops. Are you using the default instance of FrmINI?

Comment: I suspect that your loop is running as many times as you expect but it is just overwriting the values in the text boxes (?) Text property on each iteration. To check this put a break point on the line before the loop and step through the running code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve said, `frmAddItem.Show()` don't cause the `For Each` loop to stop. It keeps running until it reaches the last checked row. You could tell also from the fact that the `frmAddItem` form should shows the values from the last checked row. To solve this you must use `ShowDialog()` method (check this documentation: [Form.ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)) and also you have to put it **after** you have set the textboxes values or you won't see them. Also in your code you are using `cnt = 0` and `cnt < tot` but `cnt` is never incrementet so it will always be 0.